# Run function with Toast in Application Class

Tags: class, kotlin, fragment

Thank you all so much! I just started in Kotlin which probably should be called the K language (like C and F), and have found so many solutions here on this site...it's awesome!

I have an independent class file called AppTime.kt and it's declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <application
        android:name=".AppTime"

class AppTime : Application() {

    fun burntToast(sMsg: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

It doesn't run when called anywhere from a Fragment class:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {...

    AppTime().burntToast()
```

I've tried every approach using parameters for the Toast following makeText(...
and then to call it from a Fragment with or without context or string parameters.

Is it the type of class I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions defined inside a class can only be called on an instance of that class, as you already found.

But you cannot simply instantiate an arbitrary Application and expect it to work. Android does a lot of behind-the-scenes setup of framework classes before they are usable. Any Application or Activity that you instantiate yourself is useless. You have to use the instances that are provided to you through the lifecycle of the Activities that get launched in your application.

If you want to call this function from your Fragment, you will have to get an instance of your application, which you can get from its associated Activity. Since the Activity class doesn't know about your specific subclass of Application, you must also cast the application to your specific subclass to be able to call its unique functions. You can get the Activity by using `requireActivity()`.

```
(requireActivity().application as AppTime).burntToast()
```

Comment: And, I can call it with a string parameter too! I don't know how to thank you all...

Comment: Very sorry, new to this. I want to understand this insightful call so I found it can also be structured in two lines: val sMsg = requireActivity().application as AppTime and the second line is sMsg.burntToast(). I can declare the val one time, and make just the call again as needed.

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Comment: No, it's not a question, thanks though. The idea behind this was just to write code outside of the fragment and to call on modules. As it turns out, with your help I can also set one variable and then call the Toast function with one line and a string parameter whenever I need it. It's like a message box function in debugging.

Comment: Yes, it's safe to cache the Application in a property because it behaves like a singleton for the life of each session of your app running.